# Newbie: C syntax error when compiling

Tags: c, for-loop, comma-operator

```
    for(int a = 0, b = 1; b < n; a++; b++)
    {
        if (compare(values[a], values[b]))
            counter++;
        else
            {
            int x = values[a];
            values[a] = values[b];
            values[b] = x;
            }
    }
```

I get this error for the first line [ for(int... ] when I try to compile:

```
helpers.c:68:41: error: expected ')' before ';' token
```

Why would I need to add another ')'?

Comment: looks like a bubble sort to me :P

Comment: When you see an error like "error: expected ')' before ';' token" there are two ways to look at it. Either you need an extra ')' as you suspected, or as is the case here, you need to remove a ';'. A useful trick is to consider both possibilities.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
for(int a = 0, b = 1; b < n; a++; b++)
                                ^
                                |
                              problem
```

You need a comma (`,`) rather than a semicolon (`;`) at the end of your `for`-loop where you increment both `a` and `b`:

```
for(int a = 0, b = 1; b < n; a++, b++)
                                ^
```

This is the [comma operator](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx4db.html).

These two SO questions might also be helpful: [How do I put two increment statements in a C++ 'for' loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232176/how-to-put-2-increment-statements-in-c-for-loop)
and [What is the full "for" loop syntax in C (and others in case they are compatible)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276512/what-is-the-full-for-loop-syntax-in-c-and-others-in-case-they-are-compatible)