# Unclear behavior of "," operator in C

Tags: c, comma-operator

In a given code I found following sequence,

```
data = POC_P_Status, TE_OK;
```

I don't understand what that does mean.

Does the data element receive the first or the second element or something else?

Update:

I read somewhere that this behavior is like this,

if i would write that:

> if(data = POC_P_Status, TE_OK) {   ... }

then teh if clause will be true if TE_OK is true.

What do you mean?

Comment: `(data = POC_P_Status), TE_OK;` assignment has higher precedence than comma.

Comment: @DanielFischer according to the wikipedia page it has nothing to do with precedence. It is how the operator works: "evaluates its first operand and discards the result, and then evaluates the second operand and returns this value "

Comment: @BartFriederichs Precedence is how you tell that the first operand of `,` is `data = POC_P_Status` rather than just `POC_P_Status`.

Comment: @Bart But you determine what are its first and second operands by the rules of precedence.

Comment: @BartFriederichs The precedence determines the syntax tree, whether it's `(data = POC_P_Status), TE_OK;` or `data = (POC_P_Status, TE_OK);`. If the comma operator had a higher precedence than assignment, it would be the second.

Comment: You can always [try and see](http://ideone.com/zIV0ej).

Comment: This question is yet another reason no to use the comma operator.

Comment: @DanielDaranas Certainly the update expression in a for-loop gets an exemption?

Comment: @DanielFischer See the interesting discussion [in this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1232195/96780).

Comment: @DanielFischer I thought you were talking about precedence rules, not about my recommendation no to use the comma operator. In "for" I find it acceptable, because it is intuitive. However, I still prefer update expressions _without_ the comma operator.

Comment: @Peter [**Try and see.**](http://ideone.com/xezgIc) Also `@all` in comments doesn't do anything meaningful.

Comment: @DanielDaranas Ah, I wondered. Yes, I was referring to the use.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the comma operator \`,\` do in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550/what-does-the-comma-operator-do-in-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's equivalent to the following code:

```
data = POC_P_Status;
TE_OK;
```

In other words, it assigns `POC_P_Status` to `data` and evaluates to `TE_OK`.
In your first case, the expression stands alone, so `TE_OK` is meaningful only if it's a macro with side effects. In the second case, the expression is actually part of an `if` statement, so it always evaluates to the value of `TE_OK`. The statement could be rewritten as:

```
data = POC_P_Status;
if (TE_OK) { ... }
```

From the C11 draft (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf) :

> The left operand of a comma operator is evaluated as a void
>   expression; there is a sequence point after its evaluation. Then the
>   right operand is evaluated; the result has its type and value. If
>   an attempt is made to modify the result of a comma operator or to
>   access it after the next sequence point, the behavior is undeﬁned.

That means that in the expression:

```
a, b
```

The `a` is evaluated and thrown away, and then `b` is evaluated. The value of the whole expression is equal to `b`:

```
(a, b) == b
```

Comma operator is often used in places where multiple assignments are necessary but only one expression is allowed, such as `for` loops:

```
for (int i=0, z=length; i < z; i++, z--) {
    // do things
}
```

Comma in other contexts, such as function calls and declarations, is **not** a comma operator:

```
int func(int a, int b) {...}
              ^
              |
              Not a comma operator

int a, b;
     ^
     |
     Not a comma operator
```

Comment: While this is all true, it doesn't actually answer the question which was "What does `x = y, z` do?"

Answer (score 7):

It stores `POC_P_Status` into `data`.

```
i = a, b;   // stores a into i.
```

This is equivalent to

```
(i = a), b;
```

because the comma operator has lower precedence than assignment.

Comment: Why in a return statement like: return a, b; it will always return b ? Comma operator have higher precedence in this case ?

Comment: @dotixx, there is no assignment there, so no precedence issue.

Comment: @dotixx The comma operator takes two expressions as operands. `return something` is not an expression, so `return (a,b);` is the only possible way to parse it.