# multiple conditions in for loop - C

Tags: c, for-loop, multiple-conditions

I need to execute two conditions for i and j simultaneously.

condition for i:   `for(i=1*counter; i<= len*7*counter; i++)`

condition for j: `for(j=len*7*counter; j>=1*counter; j--)`

And then, when both these conditions are true, i need to execute `bin[i-1]=temp[j-1];`

What is the correct way of writing this?

Note: This is not a nested loop.

Is this the correct way?

`for(i=1*counter && j=a*counter; i<=a*counter && j>=1*counter; i++ && j--)`

Comment: You need to learn what `&&` means...

Comment: Well he *did* say simultaneously. Pthreads, perhaps?

Comment: @YusufX - I doubt he means "concurrently"

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to put two increment statements in a C++ 'for' loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232176/how-to-put-two-increment-statements-in-a-c-for-loop)

Answer (score 6):

To execute two conditions you need to separate them by comma (they will execute only once):

```
for( i = 1*counter, j = a*counter;
```

Use logical **AND** operator in order to "unite" these conditions:

```
i <= a*counter && j >= 1*counter;
```

Separate `i++` and `j--` by comma too:

```
i++, j-- )
```

Now, you have exactly what you need:

```
for( i = 1*counter, j = a*counter; i <= a*counter && j >= 1*counter; i++, j-- )
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for(i=1*counter, j=a*counter; i<=a*counter && j>=1*counter; i++, j--)
```