# Cannot understand for loop with two variables

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, declaration

When I use two variables in a for loop with different conditions two conditions like I have used below `i<3,j<2` the for loop is always executing till the second condition fails.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std ;
int main()
{
int i,j ;
for(i=0,j=0;i<3,j<2;i++,j++)
{
    cout<<"hello" ;
}
getch() ;
return 0 ;
}
```

In that code, `hello` is printed 2 times. Why?

If I use `i<3,j<10`, "Hello" is printed 10 times. I can't understand why the first condition is being neglected. Is it compiler dependent or something else?

Every thing works normal if I replace with conditions like || (OR) or &&(AND).An other thing is that I cannot initialize i and j in the for loop itself, it is showing me an error, but works fine when I declare variables in C style or one variable outside the for loop, why is it so?

Compiler I have used is Orwell Dev C++.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You, like many other confused people, ran into the comma operator.

Comment: `i<3,j<2` is an interesting way to write a condition... (compilable, but ...)

Comment: go through this: it mght help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232176/how-to-put-two-increment-statements-in-a-c-for-loop?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Not so much "interesting" as it is just attempting to be confusing.  The first part gets discarded, so you could say, "i > 0, j < 2" and it would do the same thing.

Comment: `g++-4.8` `7:14: warning: left operand of comma operator has no effect`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`for(i=0,j=0;i<3,j<2;i++,j++)`

is equivalent to

`for(i=0,j=0;j<2;i++,j++)`

The comma expression takes on the value of the last  expression.

Whichever condition is first, will be disregarded, and the second one will be used only.

Comment: But why is it that i cant declare i and j in the loop itself.The second part of the question in the post

Comment: @Arun may be you should re-visit `for` loop, from a good book

Comment: @Arun You don't show us the code that generated the error nor the specific error you got, so we could only guess.

Answer (score 7):

The `for` loop consists of:

`for(START_STATEMENT; CONDITION_EXPRESSION, LOOP_EXPRESSION) BODY_BLOCK`

Where:

- `START_STATEMENT` is any *single* statement, which may include variable declaration. If you want to declare 2 variables, you can write `int i=0, j=0`, but not `int i=0; int j=0` because the latter are actually 2 statements. Also node, that variable declaration is a part of statement, but cannot be a part of (sub) *expression*. That is why `int i=0, int j=0` would also be incorrect.
- `CONDITION_EXPRESSION` is any *single* expression that evaluates to a boolean value. In your case you are using a *coma operator* which has the following semantics: `A, B` will do:

  - evaluate A (it will evaluate, not just ignore)
  - ditch the result of A
  - evaluate B
  - return B as the result

  In your case: `i<3,j<2` you *are* comparing `i<3`, you are just ignoring the result of this comparison.

  Comma expressions are useful when the instructions have some side effects, beyond just returning a value. Common cases are: variable increment/decrement or assignment operator.
- `LOOP_EXPRESSION` is any *single* expression that does not have to evaluate to anything. Here you are using the comma expression again, ignoring the result of the left-hand-side. In this case however, you are not using the result anyway, and just using the ++ side effect - which is to increment the values of your variables.
- `BODY_BLOCK` is either a single statement or a block, encapsulated with curly braces.

The above `for` can be compared to:

```
{
    START_STATEMENT;
    while(EXPRESSION) {
        BODY_BLOCK;
        LOOP_EXPRESSION;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why 'continue' instruction? It doesn't modify anything.

Comment: Not really needed. It was there in previous (incorrect) version which I quickly corrected, but left it there.

Comment: Ok, so I'd like it ;)

Answer (score -1):

The c complier always used second condition.

therefore j<2 is used.

use this for loop

```
      for(i=0,j=0;j<10;i++,j++)
```