# Can I have two initializing statements in a "for" loop?

Tags: c++, for-loop, statements

In C++, a `for` loop normally takes three statements, in the form:

```
for (init; condition; step)
{
Loop statements
}
```

Can I place two or more statements in the place of `init`? Let's say I want to define two starting variables, `a` and `b`. To do this, I would use `int a = 1; int b = 5;`. However, since there is a `;` between the statements, C++ would interpret `int b = 5` as the condition statement. Is there a way to clump the whole statement into `init`, perhaps by using brackets? Can something similar be done for `step`?

Note: I am aware that I can initialize a variable before calling `for`. However, I feel that it would be more logical to place loop-related statements within the definition of the loop.

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1232182/57135

Comment: @Joe The fact that the answer from another question answers this question accidentally doesn't make this one a duplicate. Questions are different.

Comment: The [comma operator](http://www.mindtribe.com/2011/07/forgotten-c-the-comma-operator/) is not limited to `for` loops.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can only have one initializing statement. However, frequently you can use the comma operator to achieve the desired result:

```
for(int foo = 7, bar = 42; ...; ...) {
    ...
}
```

or even

```
int foo;
double bar;
for(foo = 7, bar = 42; ...; ...) {
    ...
}
```

What is not possible, is to declare two variables of different type within the initialization statement:

```
//Illegal code!
for(int foo = 7, double bar = 42; ...; ...) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Why can't we do this yet in the latest C++ 

Answer (score 4):

try `for (int a =1, b=5; condition; a++,b++) {}`

#### Update

Not everything is possible but some pretty amazing things can be achieved by calling a function inside.

```
void bar() { /* some of the code you want */ }

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int i = 0;
  for(bar();i < 10; i++) {
    // your stuff
  }
}
```

if you consider using C++11 you can define and call an unnamed function in the place where you would initialize your variables like this:

```
int a = 0, b = 1;
for ([&a, &b]{ a = b++; b = foo(a); }(); b < 10; a++) {}
```

I don't see any benefit of doing this though.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I was looking for a way to combine any two statements, not a way to fuse `int a;` and `int b;`. For the sake of argument, the statements may be variable definitions, function calls, `cout << stuff;`, anything which normally ends with `;`. Is there a way to clump them together?

Comment: care to give an idea what you want to achieve by that? doing scoped allocation might be difficult. alot of other things might be possible.

Comment: I had nothing particular in mind. I'm merely trying to learn all of the possibilities I have with the language. Unfortunately, in this case there doesn't seem to be any concise way to clump statements together.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have more that one initializing statements where more than one types are declared. **You can however** mimic that with **the following hack** :

```
for (struct { int a; char b; } i = {1, 'x'}; i.a < 15; ++i.a, ++i.b) 
{
    // ...
}
```

This way, you're **using an unnamed** struct to aggregate multiple variables of various types, and yes, this is [**valid C++**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e006097521720394).

This also works in `if` statements. Be careful though to wrap assignments in parenthesis:

```
if (struct { int* a; float* b; } i;
    (i.a = getA())
    && (i.b = getB()))
{
    // ...
}
else
{
    // Not valid
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can have more than two INITIALIZING statements, as much as you want,
but delimit them by a comma `,` :

```
for(a=1, b=25, c='C', d=25.0; b>a; a++){
}
```

but you cant have more than one declaration statement , and the declared variables must be in the first of statements :

```
for(int a=1, b=25, c='C', d=25.0; b>a; a++){}
```

not :

```
for(a=1, int b=25, c='C', d=25.0; b>a; a++){} // wrong !
```

,,,

you can also have multiple conditions or instructions ,
this is an example , the second two tests have no effect but it is just for demonstrating :

```
int i;
for(char a='A', i=0; i<26 || a+i<='Z' && a+i>='A' ;i++ , printf("-") ){
    printf("%c", a+i);
}
```

this will print : A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I-J-K-L-M-N-O-P-Q-R-S-T-U-V-W-X-Y-Z-

,,,

good luck,

Answer (score 0):

Separate with commas.

```
for(grunt, snarl; foo; goo) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 for(<initialization> ; <condition> ; <increment/decrement variables>){}
```

Initialization and increment/decrement of variables can be multiple separated by comma.
   But condition will be single,i.e. we cannot have multiple conditions separated by comma.

```
e,g.  for(i=1,j=2,k=3,l=4;j<6;k++,j--,++i,l++){}.
```