# Can you explain me (int i=0; i<8; i++, data>>=1)?

Tags: arduino

I know that the for loop needs to be in the form of 
for (initialization; condition; increment)
In this case there is a fourth part, do you know what it does?

Comment: There are only 3 parts. There are only two `;` in your code. Maybe you mistake the comma for a semicolon.

Comment: the C comma operator *is* somewhat rarely seen. If we don't already have a suitable answer around here, it wouldn't hurt to write one :)

Comment: I did not do any mistake. I tested the code and it works. Hence this for loop it is correct. 
Another for loop that is used in the code is for (int b=0; b<4; b++, freq>>=8).
I am confused

Comment: Is that even valid syntax?? "Data>>=1"? ..can't be.

Comment: The mistake is that you said there are 4 parts but actually there are only 3 parts.  The parts are separated by the `;` symbol

Comment: @GisMofx It is valid syntax, what part of it are you not sure about

Comment: @M.M I got your point and you are right.

Comment: @M.M I just looked it up. That bitwise assignment. Never used it before. Andreas it appears it's doing i++ and data = data >>1 on each loop iteration.

Comment: Also, @Andreas your answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232176/how-to-put-two-increment-statements-in-a-c-for-loop

Comment: @GisMOfx and M.M  Thank you for your help. I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no fourth part.  The third part contains the comma operator which simply allows you to put various statements together as if one where you can't use `{}`.  Pretty much the only time I've ever used them is like this (and `while` ) where you have a single place where you want to do more than one thing.

In this case, the last part of the loop is both incrementing i (`i++`) and shifting `data` right once (dividing by 2) at the end of each iteration