# Setting int using for loop in one line?

Tags: c#

I'm interested in doing something like this (C#):

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
     sum += i;
```

But I would like to do it on one line. Something like:

```
int sum = (embedded loop)
```

Is there any way to do this on one line? I'm looking to apply this to a more complex string manipulation algorithm so I can't simply replace the loop with an arithmatic formula.

Comment: Is there a reason?

Comment: Sum = n* (n+1) / 2

Comment: @TPN1994 has the formula for it, which is the *right solution*, but you could also do `var sum = Enumerable.Range(0,5).Sum();`

Comment: I'm looking to apply this to a more complex algorithm that returns a manipulated string so I can't replace the loop with a formula; it actually needs to have an embedded loop. And I am trying to do this as part of a one-line coding challenge. Thanks!

Comment: @DanielG: Then give a better example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: _And I am trying to do this as part of a one-line coding challenge_ - then @TPN1994 have provided most efficient answer for your challenge - it is one line, and do not need loop

Comment: @MattBurland I'm trying to loop through a list of words and make each one title case, then return the string[].join(" ") of it

Answer (score 6):

So you want to loop and do *something* in one line?

First off, writing it in one line isn't going to make it run faster. You are still going to loop, you are still going to be `O(n)`. For the particular problem you have in your question you can do something like:

```
var sum = Enumerable.Range(0,5).Sum();
```

This will basically make a collection of the numbers 0,1,2...4 and sum them.

More generally, since you want to do *something*, you might use the `Aggregate` function. For example:

```
var str = Enumerable.Range(0,5).Aggregate("",(p,c) => p + c); // Note: not efficient at all
```

Will take the values 0,1,...4 and do string concatenation with them (using a string builder would be better) to give you the string `01234`.

**Edit:**

> I'm trying to loop through a list of words and make each one title case, then return the string[].join(" ") of it

In that case, something like:

```
var result = string.Join(" ", myListOfWords.Select(w => char.ToUpper(w[0]) + w.Substring(1)));
```

Should work fine.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. I know it sounds stupid but it's for a challenge and it's not meant to be efficient.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind that 'sum' only is in scope of the for loop you could do this:

```
for (int i = 0, sum = 0; i < 5; sum += i, ++i) { // do something }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0,sum = 0; i<5; sum+=i,++i){}
```

Comment: BTW, it is a duplicated question since it is already indicated here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232176/how-do-i-put-two-increment-statements-in-a-c-for-loop

Comment: That&#39;s not what I was asking though. This is two lines.

Comment: Fair well, if you only want sum to be see in the scope then you can just put them in 1 line. And I don't think C# can declare a loop scope and a variable outside that scope in one single line though.