# C++ while loops and for loops not working

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, while-loop

First, I'll send the code.

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

  int times = 0;
  cout << "Enter a number of candies:";
  int number;
  cin >> number;

  while (number >= 1000) {
    cout << "Please enter an integer number between 0 and 999.\n";
    cin >> number;

  }


  for (times <= 10; times++; number--) {
    cout << "nomnom I have" << number - 1 << "candies left.\n";
   }




}
```

I am trying to practice c++ because I'm a beginner so I made a little program that is supposed to allow you to enter a number between 1 and 999, then this is gonna be the number of candies. Then, it says how many there are left. It's not working though. Can anyone tell me why? Thanks.

Comment: Any error messages?

Comment: It just doesn't work after the first cin

Comment: The first time the for loop is evaluated `times` is 0, so it is not entered. The `times <= 10` part doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

You should have your for loop formatted like this:

```
  for (; times <= 10; times++, number--) {
    cout << "nomnom I have" << number - 1 << "candies left.\n";
   }
```

The format of the for loop follows the following rule:

```
for(<initializer, which you can skip> ; <condition for execution which is required> ; <increment or decrement of the variable which you are bounding with the condition, this part is not required either>)
```

Within the initializer part you can create multiple variables, you just need to separate them with a ",", the same rule applies to the final part of the for loop. Neither the initializer not the modifier at the end are required for correct syntax. This is a valid example:

```
int i = 0;
for(; i < 5;)
{
   ++i;
}
```

For example:

```
for(int i = 0, j = 5; i < 5 && j > 0; ++i, --j){}
```

```
int i = 0, j = 5;
for(; i < 5 && j > 0; ++i, --j){}
```

```
int i = 0, j = 5;
for(; i < 5 && j > 0;){
  ++i;
  --j;
}
```

All of these examples are accomplishing the same task of incrementing i and decrementing j.

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop is incorrect - it should be done according to this:
`for( <initialization> ; <checking> ; <run_in_each_loop> ){ ...}`

You can read more about `for` loop [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_for_loop.asp).

---

You want your code to do 2 "increments" (`<run_in_each_loop>`). You can't do this using `;` in between

> A common idiom is to use the comma operator which evaluates both
>   operands, and returns the second operand. Thus:
>
> `for(int i = 0; i != 5; ++i,++j) 
>       do_something(i,j);`

read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232176/how-do-i-put-two-increment-statements-in-a-c-for-loop).

Other way would be to put `number--` inside of `{ ... }` brackets.

---

In the end, your code should look like that:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

  int times = 0;
  cout << "Enter a number of candies:";
  int number;
  cin >> number;

  while (number >= 1000) {
    cout << "Please enter an integer number between 0 and 999.\n";
    cin >> number;
  }

  for (  ; times <= 10; times++, number--) {
    cout << "nomnom I have" << number << "candies left.\n";
   }

   return;
}
```

Comment: So I have to write for ( int times = 1; number < 1000 && times <=10; number--) ?

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close!  There was just a slight issue with the `for` loop syntax:

The first part of the for loop is actually the initializer, the middle bit is the conditional, and the last bit is the iterator, it's a bit different than the while loop.

Here is what you probably meant to do:

```
  for (times = 0; times < 9; number--, times++) {
    cout << "nomnom I have" << number - 1 << "candies left.\n";    
  }
```

Comment: I tried doing that, but it gives me an error message.